# Send an event to call a method between two classes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, events

How can I invoke a method in a class only after verifying a condition in another method of another class in my iPhone app?

Any ideas?

Thanks, Andrea

**edit 3**

```
//class1 

//Class1.m


@implementation Class1 {

 ....

    [class2  method1:@"file1.xml"];

    [class2  method1:@"file2.xml"];

    [class2  method1:@"file3.xml"];
} 
        ….

  @end
```

---

```
  //class2

#import "Class1.h"  


@implementation Class2{

-(void) method1(NSString *)file{

   [self method2];

 }


-(void) method2{

   //when finish that method I have to call the successive method [class2  method1:@"file2.xml"]; in class1

 }

}
```

---

hope this help to understand (even better) the problem...

Comment: What's wrong with just sending the message the normal way [someObj someMessage] ?

Comment: I have to be sure that the method have finished its execution

Comment: I edited the question... hope it's clearer..

Comment: What is not working here? Btw, `endingCollection` is a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use delegation.  Making class 1 class 2's delegate lets class 2 send messages to class 1.

**Edit changes:** You want class2 to be the delegate of class 1.  This means that class 1 will tell class 2 to perform method1 with whatever comes after after the colon.  This can be any object.  In the example, I used a string.  Process method1 as you normally do, but remember that the xmlFile variable should be used instead of a hardcoded object, i.e. use xmlFile instead of @"file1.xml".

**EDITED** Example:

**class 1 .h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
..etc

//a protocol declaration must go before @interface
@protocol class1Delegate
-(void)method1:(NSString *)xmlFile;
@end


@interface class1 {
 id <class1Delegate> delegate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <class1Delegate> delegate;
@end
```

Synthesize delegate in your .m

Then call `[delegate method1:@"file1"]`.

**class 2 .h:**

```
#import "class1.h"

@interface class2 <class1Delegate> {
//put whatever here
}

- (void)method1:(NSString *)xmlFile;
```

Comment: Thanks.But if I have to change the parameter passed to method1 every time I have to re-invoke it, Have I to insert every call into the doMethod1 method?

Comment: Are file1 file2 etc objects or parameters? I.e. your function calls method1:@"name" file1:@"something" or is file1 passed into method1?

Comment: file1, file2 etc are parameters. I.e. [class2 method1:@"file.xml"];

Comment: So am I right in thinking that you call method1 then method2, and then restart with the next file?

Comment: Edited!  Please let me know if I'm explaining things well and if I got the gist of what you're doing.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'll try it as soon as possible, unfortunately not before monday. Sorry

Comment: nothing working... re-edit to explain the problem as better I can the problem.

Comment: I solve the problem changing the position from where I call the methods. Thank you anyway for your help, you explained well your way to solve the problem, maybe I wasn't able to catch that enaugh.